Incompatibility between LFM and LSM
In an excellent textbook by Brigo & Mercurio (2006), there is an equation I coundn't derive. It's (6.40) (p.245, shown below) about the forward-rate dynamics under the forward-swap measure.
I'd like to understand its derivation. Do you know how to compute and derive the equation?

